# @ with sql and java

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

when i tried to get email from my DB on intellij it always shows me that the email is something like this: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@4c89299.
how could i fix it.

and that's the code.

DBHandler:

```
public ResultSet getAllmessages(String reciever) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Const.MESSAGES_TABLE + " WHERE " + Const.MESSAGES_RECIEVER + "=?";


    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, reciever);
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    return resultSet;
}
```

where i take the email:

```
DBHandler databasehandler = new DBHandler();
ResultSet maild = databasehandler.getAllmessages(databasehandler.getMail(indexController.userId).toString().trim());
ResultSet resultSet =  databasehandler.getAllmessages((maild).toString().trim())
```

Comment: Dont print the result set but extract / map the contents to something meaningful.

Comment: how should i do it?

Comment: `(maild).toString()` - what do you think this will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get ResultSet object you have to get values like this.

```
resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME1");
resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_NAME2");
```